# How can I grab the whole word in the Javascript autofill

Tags: javascript, html

How can I modify the following code so when I click on the element grab the whole word
I have no idea from javascript and I need this feature

code it's from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {


    var currentFocus;

    inp.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
        var a,
            b,
            i,
            val = this.value;

        closeAllLists();
        if (!val) {
            return false;
        }
        currentFocus = -1;

        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list-invoice");
        a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items-invoice");

        this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

                b = document.createElement("DIV");

                b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);

                b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";

                b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

                    inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

                    closeAllLists();
                });
                a.appendChild(b);
            }
        }
    });

    inp.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list-invoice");
        if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {

            currentFocus++;

            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {

            currentFocus--;

            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {

                if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
            }
        }
    });
    function addActive(x) {

        if (!x) return false;

        removeActive(x);
        if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = x.length - 1;

        x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active-invoice");
    }
    function removeActive(x) {

        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active-invoice");
        }
    }
    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {

        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items-invoice");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
}

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput_invoice"), promList);
```

with the following let's say I type 'ma' and I click on Maura then

```
var user_input = document.getElementById("myInput_invoice").value;
```

get the value 'ma' but I want to grab Maura

Comment: If you take the `value` after the click, then it should contain the full word

Comment: Where do you put `document.getElementById("myInput_invoice").value;` line?

Comment: i have a function onchange at my html